# interpreting Lua code in python

Tags: python, lua, torch

I have this piece of Lua-Torch code and try to put into Python code.
I have difficulty to understand the meaning result/process of:

```
= nn.Linear(size1
t2h_d.data.module:share(
```

> 

```
   import 'nn'
   import 'nngraph'

   nh_t= nn.identity(d)
   h_d= nn.identity(d)

    size1= 5
    t2h_d = nn.Linear(size1, 4 * size1)(h_t):annotate{name='ih_'..L}  
    d2h_d = nn.Linear(size1, 4 * size1)(h_d):annotate{name='hh_'..L}  


    t2h_d.data.module:share(shared_weights[1], 'weight', 'bias', 'grdWeight', 'grdBias')
    d2h_d.data.module:share(shared_weights[2], 'weight', 'bias', 'grdWeight', 'grdBias')
```

Can somebody knows the equivalent in numpy python ?

Comment: I don't think code translation is one of the things that is considered on topic here, what have you tried in python to replicate this lua code?

Comment: it looks like its neural netwok stuff ... so http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

Comment: Nothing to do with scikit learn (this is about numpy and matrix operations)

Comment: are you sure ? nngraph is neuralnetworks ... you just said you dont understand what this code is doing... if you do know what this code is doing at least explain that ... dont put some obscure lua from some obscure lua library with almost zero context ...

Comment: I dont understand this part of Lua code: nn.Linear(size1
t2h_d.data.module:share(    as mentionned in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code in LUA

```
t2h_d.data.module:share(shared_weights[1], 'weight', 'bias')
```

means t2h_d tensor will use the used stored in share_weights[1]

```
nn.Linear(size1, 4 * size1)(h_t):annotate{name='ih_'..L}
```

means a linear product W.h_t is done and the result is called ih_L,
W has the following size:   size1, 4 * size1

Those precisions are useful since LUA nn lacks of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try a python library named "[lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy)". So you can use all the lua/torch libraries and functions in python. It also implemented features for converting between torch tensor and numpy array, which could also be interesting for you.